# Why does this mutable borrow live beyond its scope?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I've encountered a confusing error about the use of a mutable and immutable borrow at the same time, after I expect the mutable borrow to end. I've done a lot of research on similar questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40165686/borrow-errors-for-multiple-borrows), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023871/returning-a-reference-from-a-hashmap-or-vec-causes-a-borrow-to-last-beyond-the-s), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32151937/mysterious-borrow-scope-extension), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38713228/cannot-borrow-variable-when-borrower-scope-ends), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69041023/why-is-rust-pub-fn-funca-mut-self-considered-mutably-borrowed-after-run)) which has led me to believe my problem has something to do with [lexical lifetimes](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/43234) (though turning on the NLL feature and compiling on nightly doesn't change the result), I just have no idea what; my situation doesn't seem to fit into any of the scenarios of the other questions.

```rust
pub enum Chain<'a> {
    Root {
        value: String,
    },
    Child {
        parent: &'a mut Chain<'a>,
    },
}

impl Chain<'_> {
    pub fn get(&self) -> &String {
        match self {
            Chain::Root { ref value } => value,
            Chain::Child { ref parent } => parent.get(),
        }
    }

    pub fn get_mut(&mut self) -> &mut String {
        match self {
            Chain::Root { ref mut value } => value,
            Chain::Child { ref mut parent } => parent.get_mut(),
        }
    }
}

#[test]
fn test() {
    let mut root = Chain::Root { value: "foo".to_string() };

    {
        let mut child = Chain::Child { parent: &mut root };

        *child.get_mut() = "bar".to_string();
    } // I expect child's borrow to go out of scope here

    assert_eq!("bar".to_string(), *root.get());
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a38753ceef7031023bf23cdd321615d1)

The error is:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `root` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> example.rs:36:36
   |
31 |         let mut child = Chain::Child { parent: &mut root };
   |                                                --------- mutable borrow occurs here
...
36 |     assert_eq!("bar".to_string(), *root.get());
   |                                    ^^^^
   |                                    |
   |                                    immutable borrow occurs here
   |                                    mutable borrow later used here
```

I understand why an immutable borrow happens there, but I do not understand how a mutable borrow is used there. How can both be used at the same place? I'm hoping someone can explain what is happening and how I can avoid it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In short, `&'a mut Chain<'a>` is extremely limiting and pervasive.

For an immutable reference `&T<'a>`, the compiler is allowed to shorten the lifetime of `'a` when necessary to match other lifetimes or as part of NLL (this is not *always* the case, it depends on what `T` is). However, it cannot do so for mutable references `&mut T<'a>`, otherwise you could assign it a value with a shorter lifetime.

So when the compiler tries to reconcile the lifetimes when the reference and the parameter are linked `&'a mut T<'a>`, the lifetime of the reference is conceptually expanded to match the lifetime of the parameter. Which essentially means you've created a mutable borrow that will never be released.

Applying that knowledge to your question: creating a reference-based hierarchy is really only possible if the nested values are covariant over their lifetimes. Which excludes:

- mutable references
- trait objects
- structs with interior mutability

Refer to these variations on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2fb790aadf62b09ab8c72e2740f8d9b0) to see how these don't quite work as expected.

See also:

- [Why does linking lifetimes matter only with mutable references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32165917/why-does-linking-lifetimes-matter-only-with-mutable-references)
- [How do I implement the Chain of Responsibility pattern using a chain of trait objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46743353/how-do-i-implement-the-chain-of-responsibility-pattern-using-a-chain-of-trait-ob)
- [What are the differences when getting an immutable reference from a mutable reference with self-linked lifetimes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66133194/what-are-the-differences-when-getting-an-immutable-reference-from-a-mutable-refe)

---

For fun, I'll include a case where the Rust standard library does this sort of thing *on purpose*. The signature of [`std::thread::scope`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/fn.scope.html) looks like:

```
pub fn scope<'env, F, T>(f: F) -> T
where
    F: for<'scope> FnOnce(&'scope Scope<'scope, 'env>) -> T
```

The [`Scope`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/struct.Scope.html) that is provided to the user-defined function intentionally has its lifetimes tied in a knot to ensure it is only used in intended ways. This is not always the case since structs may be covariant or contravariant over their generic types, but `Scope` is defined to be invariant. Also, the only function that can be called on it is `.spawn()` which intentionally takes `&'scope self` as the self-parameter as well, ensuring that the reference does not have a shorter lifetime than what is given by `scope`.

Internally, the standard library contains this documentation ([source](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.65.0/library/std/src/thread/scoped.rs#L15-L27)):

> Invariance over `'scope`, to make sure `'scope` cannot shrink, which is necessary for soundness.
>
> Without invariance, this would compile fine but be unsound:
>
> ```
> std::thread::scope(|s| {
>     s.spawn(|| {
>         let a = String::from("abcd");
>         s.spawn(|| println!("{a:?}")); // might run after `a` is dropped
>     });
> });
> ```

Even if the lifetime of the reference is invariant with respect to itself, this still avoids many problems above because it uses an *immutable* reference and [interior-mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/interior-mutability.html). If the parameter to `.spawn()` required `&'scope mut self`, then this would not work and run into the same problems above when trying to spawn more than one thread.

Comment: Thank you.  I now understand why it doesn't work.  I think the solution I seek is in one of those links you provided, especially the Chain of Responsibility one -- that is almost exactly the pattern I'm trying to implement.

Answer (score 4):

The issue isn't lexical lifetimes, and adding an explicit `drop` won't change the error. The issue is with the `&'a mut Chain<'a>`- that forces `root` to be borrowed for its entire life, rendering it useless after the borrow is dropped. As per the comment below, doing this with lifetimes is basically impossible. I would suggest using a box instead. Changing the struct to

```
pub enum Chain{
Root {
        value: String,
    },
    Child {
        parent: Box<Chain>,
    },
}
```

and adjusting the other methods as necesary. Alternatively, using an `Rc<RefCell<Chain>>` if you want the original to remain usable without consuming self.

Comment: Thank you.  I might be able to refactor my design to use `Box`, but I'm frequently pushing and popping these Child objects at the end of the chain, so it gets harder to think about if it isn't owned by the Root.

Comment: @rmeador It might be worth trying the `Rc<RefCell<Chain>>`. The `Rc` lets you share ownership and the `RefCell` lets you enforce RAII dynamically rather than statically. Just be careful of reference cycles if you do that.