# Why can't Rust downgrade my lifetime but instead complains about type mismatch?

Tags: rust, types, lifetime

Consider the following struct:

```rust
struct State<'a> {
    parent: Option<&'a mut State<'a>>,
    // ...
}
```

My state stores some values that I might need later. Now I want to implement substates, i.e. allow the manipulation of those values in the substate without touching the parent state, but forwarding lookup of values not in the substate to its parent. Unfortunately, I need a mutable reference to every parent state at all times. I tried the following, but it doesn't work ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d5f73394d9227f2869cd55a3e2e40761)):

```rust
impl<'a> State<'a> {
    fn substate<'b>(&'b mut self) -> State<'b>
    where
        'a: 'b,
    {
        State::<'b> { parent: Some(self) }
    }
}
```

This gives the following error message:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:10:36
   |
10 |         State::<'b> { parent: Some(self) }
   |                                    ^^^^ lifetime mismatch
   |
   = note: expected mutable reference `&mut State<'b>`
              found mutable reference `&mut State<'a>`
note: the lifetime `'b` as defined here...
  --> src/main.rs:6:17
   |
6  |     fn substate<'b>(&'b mut self) -> State<'b>
   |                 ^^
note: ...does not necessarily outlive the lifetime `'a` as defined here
  --> src/main.rs:5:6
   |
5  | impl<'a> State<'a> {
   |      ^^
```

I don't understand why the compiler wants `'b` to outlive `'a`. In fact, the parent of a state will always live longer than its substate, so in my case the opposite is always true. So why can't the compiler just downgrade the "longer" lifetime `'a` into the "shorter" lifetime `'b`?

Comment: Related: [Why does this mutable borrow live beyond its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66252831/2189130)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message on nightly is better (thanks to [NLL stabilization](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/95565) that may be removed before hitting stable, but now it is there):

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:10:31
   |
5  | impl<'a> State<'a> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
6  |     fn substate<'b>(&'b mut self) -> State<'b>
   |                 -- lifetime `'b` defined here
...
10 |         State::<'b> { parent: Some(self) }
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^^ this usage requires that `'b` must outlive `'a`
   |
   = help: consider adding the following bound: `'b: 'a`
   = note: requirement occurs because of a mutable reference to `State<'_>`
   = note: mutable references are invariant over their type parameter
   = help: see <https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html> for more information about variance
```

It is not enough that `'a` outlives `'b`, it should be exactly the same since it is invariant and invariant lifetimes cannot be shortened. Look at the link the compiler gives or [the reference entry about variance](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/subtyping.html) to better understand what variance is and why mutable references are invariant.

Comment: Agreed, that error message is indeed a lot better. Is there any way to allow subtyping here? As far as I can tell, it is ok in my case to downgrade the lifetime, just the compiler doesn't know that.

Comment: @msrd0 There is no way to opt-out variance. However, using the same lifetime twice with mutable references is almost always wrong. If I'd had to guess, I would guess you are trying to create a self-referential struct and arrived at this annotation because of compiler errors. Am I correct?

Comment: Nope, nothing in there is self-referential. I just want to create substates of substates of substates ... except I need to track when I access part of the state, hence the mutable reference

Comment: @msrd0 I can't help you without more code (which will probably be appropriate for a new question), but I'm not really convinced ignoring variance here is sound. I think the "meowing dogs" problem still exists here.

Comment: I ended up using `RefCell` which, unlike mutable references, does not seem to prevent subtyping the lifetime parameter.

Comment: @msrd0 `RefCell` has interior mutability and therefore *must* be invariant over its generic parameter, so I'm curious what change you made if `RefCell` fixes it.

Answer (score 3):

The function signature is unsound, and here's an example of why:

```rust
struct State<'a> {
    parent: Option<&'a mut State<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> State<'a> {
    fn substate<'b>(&'b mut self) -> State<'b>
    where
        'a: 'b,
    {
        /* implementation hidden but assumed to be implemented as described */
    }
}
```

```rust
// [root]
let mut root = State { parent: None };

// [foo] -> [root]
let mut foo = root.substate();

{
    // [bar] -> [foo] -> [root]
    let mut bar = foo.substate();

    // [bar] -> [foo] -> [tmp]
    let mut tmp = State { parent: None };
    bar.parent.as_mut().unwrap().parent = Some(&mut tmp);

    // tmp is dropped
}

// [foo] -> {uninitialized memory}
drop(foo);
```

([Full playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=195602f718f2676de6ffb8fa21369b28))

The function signature allows us to store a reference inside `foo` here that lives shorter than `foo` itself does, so after we leave the block `foo` points to uninitialized memory, which is undefined behavior and **bad**.

If you run the above code with `cargo miri`, it will give this error, confirming that it is indeed undefined behavior:

```
error: Undefined Behavior: type validation failed at .parent.<enum-variant(Some)>.0: encountered a dangling reference (use-after-free)
  --> src/main.rs:40:10
   |
40 |     drop(foo);
   |          ^^^ type validation failed at .parent.<enum-variant(Some)>.0: encountered a dangling reference (use-after-free)
   |
   = help: this indicates a bug in the program: it performed an invalid operation, and caused Undefined Behavior
   = help: see https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html for further information

   = note: inside `main` at src/main.rs:40:10

note: some details are omitted, run with `MIRIFLAGS=-Zmiri-backtrace=full` for a verbose backtrace

error: aborting due to previous error
```