# Compilation error when calling a function defined in trait that returns a reference type: borrowed value does not live long enough

Tags: rust, lifetime

Compilation error when calling a function defined in trait that returns a reference type: borrowed value does not live long enough

Here is a sample reproduction of my problem:

```
use std::rc::Rc;

trait Bundle<'a> {
    fn id(&'a self) -> &'a str;
}

struct Demo {
    id: String,
}

impl<'a> Bundle<'a> for Demo {
    fn id(&'a self) -> &'a str {
        &self.id
    }
}

fn x(bundle: Rc<dyn Bundle<'_>>, file: &str) -> String {
    let id = bundle.id();
    format!("bundle/{}/{}", id, file)
}

fn main() {
    let demo = Rc::new(Demo {
        id: String::from("demo"),
    });
    println!("{}", x(demo as Rc<dyn Bundle>, "hello.txt"));
}
```

The compiler gives the following error:

```
error[E0597]: `bundle` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:18:14
   |
17 | fn x(bundle: Rc<dyn Bundle<'_>>, file: &str) -> String {
   |      ------ has type `Rc<dyn Bundle<'1>>`
18 |     let id = bundle.id();
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^
   |              |
   |              borrowed value does not live long enough
   |              argument requires that `bundle` is borrowed for `'1`
19 |     format!("bundle/{}/{}", id, file)
20 | }
   | - `bundle` dropped here while still borrowed
```

I'm a newbie and in my understanding, after the `format!()` statement at line 19, I no longer borrow `bundle`. So why rustc thinks it "still borrowed"?

Comment: Remove the explicit lifetime: `trait Bundle { fn id(&self) -> &str; }`.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Can you explain why this error occurs after adding the explicit lifetime `'a`? Or give some URLs for reference. @Jmb

Comment: This is basically the same issue as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66252831/5397009): by using the same lifetime in the generic argument `Bundle<'a>` and in the function prototype `id (&'a self) -> &'a str`, you're linking both lifetimes together, i.e. you're telling the compiler that `bundle` must stay borrowed as long as `demo` lives.

Answer (score 1):

I made a stupid mistake. Thanks to the answer given by @jmb in the comments section, I now changed the code to the following to fixup it:

```
use std::rc::Rc;

trait Bundle {
    fn id(&self) -> &str;
}

struct Demo {
    id: String,
}

impl Bundle for Demo {
    fn id(&self) -> &str {
        &self.id
    }
}

fn x(bundle: Rc<dyn Bundle>, file: &str) -> String {
    let id = bundle.id();
    format!("bundle/{}/{}", id, file)
}

fn main() {
    let demo = Rc::new(Demo {
        id: String::from("demo"),
    });
    println!("{}", x(demo as Rc<dyn Bundle>, "hello.txt"));
}
```

BTW, I have also tried to continue using the explicit lifecycle. The generic argument should be on the function and not on the trait.

```
trait Bundle {
    fn id<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a str;
}
```