# Traits and generic code: tell the compiler I return a "copy" so borrow is dropped

Tags: generics, rust, borrow-checker

I would like to write a generic code that uses the traits implemented by several data structures. This generic code consists in several set/get operations. I think the borrow checker throws an error because it has not enough information about the type returned by `get` in `ReadCollection` trait.

Here is a minimal example that reproduces my current problem:

```rust
trait ReadCollection<'a> {
    type Entry: Sized + Clone;
    type Iter: Iterator<Item = (usize, Self::Entry)>;

    fn iter(&'a self) -> Self::Iter;
    fn get(&'a self, row: usize) -> Self::Entry;
}

trait WriteCollection {
    type Entry: Sized + Clone;
    fn set(&mut self, row: usize, val: Self::Entry) -> ();
}

fn operation<'a, T, C>(collection: &'a mut C) -> ()
where
    C: ReadCollection<'a, Entry = T> + WriteCollection<Entry = T>,
    T: Sized + Clone,
{
    let val = collection.get(0).clone();
    collection.set(1, val);
}
```

Here is the error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*collection` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/bug/bug1.rs:22:5
   |
16 | fn elimination<'a, T, C>(collection: &'a mut C) -> ()
   |                -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
21 |     let val = collection.get(0).clone();
   |               -----------------
   |               |
   |               immutable borrow occurs here
   |               argument requires that `*collection` is borrowed for `'a`
22 |     collection.set(1, val);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
```

I understand the problem, `get` asks for `&self` and `set` for `&mut self` and it is not allowed because, as far as I understand, `T` is a set that can contain types such as `&T` and `&mut T`.

If I'm right, is there a way to tell the compiler that `get` returns `T` where `T` is always a "plain value" (e.g. a number), a copy ?

Comment: A HRTB solves this for this example code (`where C: for<'b> ReadCollection<'b, Entry = T> ...`) but without more context such as an example implementation of `ReadCollection` it's hard to say if that's a solution for your actual usecase.

Comment: `&'a mut C` with `C: ReadCollection<'a>` is a case of `&'a mut Foo<'a>`, which is [always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66253247/5397009)

Comment: Thanks a lot @cdhowie for the fix and @Jmb for the useful link. It fixes my issue and I understand what was wrong. 

I can edit the post with an example implementation if you want. What I have is basically a data structure that holds several `Vec<T>`, the whole represents a sparse vector/matrix.