Two independent variables with same lifetime
Consider code:
struct Y<'a>(&'a i32);

fn foo<'a, 'b>(x: &'a mut i32, y: &'b mut Y<'a>) {
    bar(x, y);
    // error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*x` as mutable more than once at a time
    bar(x, y);
}

fn bar<'a, 'b>(x: &'a mut i32, y: &'b mut Y<'a>) {}

Second call to bar(x, y) gives error:
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*x` as mutable more than once at a time
 --> src/main.rs:7:9
  |
5 | fn foo<'a, 'b>(x: &'a mut i32, y: &'b mut Y<'a>) {
  |        -- lifetime `'a` defined here
6 |     bar(x, y);
  |     ---------
  |     |   |
  |     |   first mutable borrow occurs here
  |     argument requires that `*x` is borrowed for `'a`
7 |     bar(x, y);
  |         ^ second mutable borrow occurs here

I don't understand this error because it doesn't say a word about y, however problem is somehow related to y because if I remove y there will be no error. But why x and y have some sort of conflict here? They are completely unrelated variables, they are not borrowing each other, etc. The only thing is that they have the same lifetime, but why it is a problem?

"They are completely unrelated variables, they are not borrowing each other, etc" But they're not: you're using the same lifetime 'a for x: &'a mut i32 and y: Y<'a> which effectively links the two. At heart, this is the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/q/66252831/5397009 where a lifetime used both in a &mut reference and as a generic parameter becomes unusable.

The lifetime 'a in &mut Y<'a> is invariant because of the mutable reference. This makes the 'a in bar() the same as the 'a in foo(). Since the latter must outlive the runtime of foo(), you can't call bar() twice.

@Jmb https://stackoverflow.com/q/66252831/5397009 is about &'a mut Y<'a>, but I have &'b mut Y<'a>. These should be different, isn't it?

You have &'a mut X and Y<'a> using the same lifetime which is fundamentally the same issue.

Your function signature dictates that the referece x is borrowed for however long Y hold its reference. So when you call bar which has that same signature, you are passing x for all of 'a. A single call would be okay, but another call means you are again trying to pass x for all of 'a, but the previous call already borrowed it for 'a. And since mutable references are exclusive, you get a conflict.
If you were to relax y to an immutable reference, &'b Y<'a>, then this would work since the compiler would be allowed to pick a shorter 'a for the calls to bar. However because mutable references' referants are invariant, the compiler cannot do that. See Subtyping and Variance.
This is preventing you from a potential error: with the signature, bar could easily do this:
fn bar<'a, 'b>(x: &'a mut i32, y: &'b mut Y<'a>) {
    y.0 = x;
}

You have constrained that the lifetimes are the same and mutable references can be downgraded to immutable references, so this compiles. Though I hope you see how this is a problem for foo attempting to call this function twice - you would get a simultaneous mutable reference (x) and an immutable reference y.0 to the same value. Rust does not allow this.

I'm no an expert on lifetime, but I believe this is because on the first bar() call, by defining lifetime of bar as
fn bar<'a>(x: &'a mut i32, y: &mut Y<'a>) {}

you are saying the mut borrow of x by bar() lives as long as y (the value it self, not the reference).
So when you call bar() the second time, because y still exists, the first mut borrow of x is also not dropped, so x cannot be mut borrowed a second time.
Notice you did not define how long the mut reference of y actually lives. If you do so:
fn foo<'a>(x: &'a mut i32, y: &'a mut Y<'a>) {
    bar(x, y);
    bar(x, y);
}

fn bar<'a>(x: &'a mut i32, y: &'a mut Y<'a>) {}

Both x and y will be shown as error having been borrowed more than once

"you are saying the mut borrow of x by bar() lives as long as y" - could you please elaborate from where it comes? As I understand reference of y will have anonymous liftime, basically fn bar<'a, 'b>(x: &'a mut i32, y: &'b mut Y<'a>) {}

Y<'a> means the lifetime 'a is as long as a Y type variable exists, when you have &'a mut x, you are saying this reference of x lives as long as the varaible y. It has nothing to do with the life time of &mut y but is realted to the life time of the varaible y references.
